# Able to fetch user details but still getting google authentication error during redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I am trying to use `passport` to google auth and log in a user.

Based on logs, I am able to fetch the user profile fine and also store it in mongodb for reuse.

Yet when after clicking the google login in UI, logs looking fine, but it doesn't redirect to the private page `/private`. Instead it throws following error.

Error is not consistent. Sometimes shows this. Other times just keeps staying on the google login page and keeps redirecting back to it.

```
InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
    at /Users/name/projects/project-name/node_modules/passport-google-oauth2/lib/oauth2.js:92:28
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/name/projects/project-name/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:162:5)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:494:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

What am I missing?

This is the entire logic.

authentication.js (doubt issue is here. This is more on db connection which is fine)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import findOrCreate from 'mongoose-findorcreate'
import {DB_CLUSTER, DB_NAME, DB_OPTIONS, DB_PASSWORD, DB_USERNAME} from "./secrets.js";

export const createDbConnections = async () => {

  const connectionString = `mongodb+srv://${DB_USERNAME}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_CLUSTER}/${DB_NAME}?${DB_OPTIONS}`;

  mongoose.connect(connectionString, { useNewUrlParser: true });

  const db = await mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

  db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  });
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: String,
  googleId: String
});

userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

export const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

This is the main index.js file with the auth and routes.

```
import passport from 'passport';
import {Strategy} from 'passport-google-oauth2';
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import {config} from "dotenv";
import {createDbConnections, User} from "./authentication.js";
import {COOKIE_SESSION_SECRET, GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, PORT} from "./secrets.js";

const app = express();
app.use(session({
  secret: COOKIE_SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
config();

await createDbConnections(); // connecting to mongo db no issues here.

passport.use('google', new Strategy({
    clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: `/auth/google/callback`,
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
  },
  (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, (err, user) => {
      console.log(user)
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));



app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  (req, res) => {
    req.login(req.user, err => {
      if (err) { return res.send('Error during callback req.login portion'); }

      console.log(`I reach here fine ${req.user}`)
      return res.redirect('/private');
    });
  });

app.get('/private', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }), (req, res) => {
  console.log('Issue is here. I never reach here.')
  res.send('private spot');
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    // User is already logged in, render the homepage
    res.redirect('/private');
  } else {
    // User is not logged in, render the login page
    res.send(`Go and login @ http://localhost:${PORT}/auth/google`);
  }
});

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Go and authenticate @ http://localhost:${PORT}/auth/google`);
});
```